# Why newlines are not color-formatted?

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors, terminal

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21786287/4551565) solution in order to color-format a matrix on the terminal. However when I print it, the newlines I have added in order to separate the lines of the matrix are not formatted. I expected the whole terminal to become background white and black text (for the area corresponding to the matrix height), but clearly it is not. Why?

This is the code:

```
m = np.full((4,4),'0',dtype=np.str_)
print('\x1b[0;30;47m\n'+'\n\n'.join('   '+'   '.join(line) for line in m)+'\n\x1b[0m')
```

**PROOF**:
[image]
I am using the default ubuntu 14.04 terminal

**SOLVED**
In the end I simply applied the color-formatting to each string of characters separated by a new line.

Comment: Can you provide evidence that this clearly does not work as expected?

Comment: I just tried it in my console and I can confirm it does not work as he expects. Huh, I just tried again after I said that and it worked fine.... and then I tried again and it doesn't work again. Jeez, this comment is useless.

Comment: what terminal are you using?

Comment: @ScottHunter question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason for this behaviour is that most terminals only apply background colour to the characters that are actually printed, but `\n\n` produces a line containing **no** characters (rather than a line full of spaces). At least that's what all the terminals I had at hand did. Try this:

```
print('\x1b[0;30;47m\n' + '\n'.join([' '*i for i in range(10)]) + '\n\x1b[0m')
```

and you'll likely see a stair-like pattern: [image: stair-like pattern]

Answer (score 1):

Cell backgrounds are colored only where the screen is updated.  When your program prints a newline, it "only" makes the cursor position move down (no cells are updated).

However, if you modify your program to print more lines, i.e., going down to the bottom of the screen, it will do something different:

- the cursor can no longer move down.
- the screen "indexes" (scrolls up by one line), and
- the newly exposed line will be colored.

That is because the terminal copies the behavior from xterm and Linux console.  There are actually several features of the terminal which combine to form its behavior when erasing portions of the screen.

Further reading:

- the ncurses FAQ *[My terminal shows some uncolored spaces](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#bce_mismatches)*
- [an interesting bug report...](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=754596)